# magento admin usernames

Tags: magento

Does anybody knows if it is possible to set up admin user accounts so every potential user of the admin panel has their own login details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, in the admin panel go to *System->Permissions->Users*, here you can add and edit all of your admin users.

Answer (score 1):

Not only admin rights but you can create all kinda rights to any user

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-09-28_1221.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-09-28_1221.png)

The set up the Roles first, Roles is a group of access that you want to permit users to perform, for example, I have a **INVOICE role**, so I can let some users and API Calls to request information only to Invoices and the Dashboard

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-09-28_1225.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-09-28_1225.png)

Last part is the easiest, assign the role(s) to the user

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-09-28_1227.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-09-28_1227.png)